# Assign IDs to elements (tables) in accordion sections

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a page called with a list of items.  I iterate through the list like this:

```
 <div id="accordion">
   @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <h3 id= '@Model[i].UserId' class="header">@Model[i].UserName</h3>
            <div >
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].UserId, new { @id = "txtId" + i })
                <table style="font-size:xx-small">
```

My question is - how do I assign an ID for each table in each accordion group so that I can manipulate it later?  I've tried this:

```
 <table id="tbl" + '@Model[i].UserId' style="display:none", class="userTable">
```

But that doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: why you have `,` after `style`? Also try to post rendered `html`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao - good question, I don't know, a mistake.  But I need an answer not a critique.

Comment: That wasn't **critique** buddy.. That was just a hint where you might have gone wrong while trying to attempt for the solution.. or just to correct the invalidity..

Comment: Ok tell me what you get as rendered `html` when you do `id="tbl" + '@Model[i].UserId'`?

Comment: Just the "tbl" as the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try change to

```
<table id="tbl" + @Model[i].UserId style="display:none" class="userTable">
```

Comment: Please try again, I changed a little

Answer (score 0):

You just need

```
<table id="tbl@Model[i].UserId" style="display:none" class="userTable">
```

`@` will take care of all the other things.

Comment: I can also provide you a better approach with `foreach` if you wish to change?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input guys - but this solved it:

```
 <table id='tbl @Model[I].UserId' class="userTable"...
```

The space is required in order for the Razor to interpret the value.  It does come back with a space between but I can still access it.

```
 var tbl = $(chk).closest('tr').next().find('.userTable');
            $(tbl).slideDown().show();
```

The chk is a checkbox to show details for the user in the table.

Comment: space is not necessary. You can still give it the way I have given in my answer. You just need it for you compatibility purpose. You can either use `_` to separate the concern of `UserID`. Anyways.. Happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

you should change to

```
<table id ="tbl@Model[i].UserId" style ="display:none" class= "userTable">
```